# Stream with OpenCV from client to Django server

Tags: django, opencv, streaming, webrtc, django-channels

I'm looking for a solution for the following:

I have a server with a Django backend to be used as a kind of chat app with a chat room that will be used to connect two clients. For that I'm using [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Client A connects to the chat room and is able to send messages to client B using this toy example (running in client B):

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
ws_url = "ws://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/ws/chat/loby/"
async def command_receiver():
    async with websockets.connect(ws_url) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            message = json.loads(message)
            print("Received: ",message["message"])
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(command_receiver())
```

Now I want that client B streaming its webcam using for example OpenCV in response to client A message. In the same python script, I want to capture the webcam stream using, for example, this [solution](https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/5bd13f27e2cc4c4b32f9c618fe0a7ee5). It would be something like to this:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import cv2
import numpy as np


ws_url = "ws://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/ws/chat/loby/"
async def command_receiver():
    async with websockets.connect(ws_url) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            message = json.loads(message)
            if message["message"] == "send_stream":

                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
                currentFrame = 0
                while(True):
                    # Capture frame-by-frame
                    ret, frame = cap.read()

                    # Handles the mirroring of the current frame
                    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)

                    #send frames in real time...

                    #if something
                    break

                # When everything done, release the capture
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(command_receiver())
```

Can I use Django to receive a stream of video? If so, how? And would it be a good solution?

Or in response to the message can I use WebRTC to connect client B to A? If so, how can I do that from the python script running in B?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Yes but not a good one. You can use django channel to open a room that will connect A and B, where client A is connected to the web socket via browser and B via a python script. Then you just need to convert each frame to a string and send it to the room. You can then consume the frame with javascript in A browser and show it as an image.  The problem with this solution is that is quite slow. I'm now trying to use WebRTC the stream directly.